# Finding the tags of questions I have answered

Tags: support, search, tag-search

Is there a way to find the tags of questions that I have interacted with **on Stackoverflow**; not this site, this question was down voted because the answerers assumed I was asking about the current site? While my question was generally about the questions on Stackoverflow; and not its meta site.

Comment: You haven't answered any questions on this meta site, so your question is a bit puzzling.

Comment: Actually I was asking about the questions that I have asked on other site. **NOTE** My questions were blocked on the main site. So I was not able to post. But now they are activated, and I will be posting! :) Thats why I was trying to know. And moreover, I was asking about the questions I HAVE ANSWERED; by other users or mine!

Comment: I'm sorry it's very unclear what you're after. Please [edit] your question to make it clearer. Look especially at your title that says "**on this meta site**" - kind of strange if you're not talking about this meta site... "Questions I have answered" means questions to which you, specifically, have posted an answer. Do you mean question you asked that got an answer (by you or someone else)?

Comment: Oops that topic is an error, my bad! and no. The questions that I have answered to someone else's. Not mine!

Comment: Isn't your profile's tag page enough for this? (There's some strange voting pattern on your profile...)

Comment: My question basically was about search, not my profile! :/

Comment: There are no search options that return a list of tags. The tag page in your profile lists all tags you've posted things about, and the scores shown there reflect your answers. I'm not really sure what more you want. Look into http://data.stackexchange.com/ though.

Comment: Your answer is helpfull! :) The link I mean.

Comment: For someone so keen on reputation, there is some two-edged irony. The serial upvotes on SO took the reputation over 200, trigerring the Association Bonus. 40 minutes later,"Serial upvoting reversed" took StackOverflow below 200 again. With all the downvotes on Meta, you still have 52 reputation, instead of one, and all those other Association bonuses. When you've "won out" by accident, stop complaining!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is tracked in your profile. There is a list of your top ten tags on the ["summary" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1762944/afzaal-ahmad-zeeshan), and the full list is on the ["tags" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1762944/afzaal-ahmad-zeeshan?tab=tags).

The number next to the tag is your total score in that tag, based on all of the non-wiki answers that you've posted to questions with that tag.

[image]

Clicking on one of the tags will take you to a list of all the questions and answers you've posted with that tag. You'll notice that this is just a search, using a query like:

```
user:42 [jquery]
```

<sup>(But that search is empty, because [Coincoin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42/coincoin) has not participated on the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tag.)</sup>